# Is a linearly ordered set equally spaced out?

Tags: stochastic-processes

When defining a *discrete - time* stochastic process, the author of An *Introduction to Discrete-Valued Time Series* states that such a process is a sequence of random variables $(X_t)_{\mathcal{T}}$ where $\mathcal{T}$ is both a discrete and linearly ordered set. Does this mean that $\mathcal{T}$ is equally spaced?

Comment: There is no notion of "spaced" (aka. metric) implied

Comment: So what does the author mean by linearly ordered? Does he just mean that the less than or equal to relation holds without contradiction for all elements of the set?

Comment: Quite.  Read more about [total orders on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order).